# Laravel pass parameter from form to controller through (not via address line/get)?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I have a form, opening like so:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('admin.application.process', $questions), 'method' => 'post')) !!}
```

And in my controller:

```
public function processApplication($questions) {
    ...
}
```

My route:

```
Route::post('process/{questions}',
    'AppController@processApplication'
);
```

However I want to transfer $questions in a more secure way, so members don't have any way to change it.

Currently the URL looks like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/process/question_for_example
```

That means anyone can replace "question_for_example" and change it.

Is there any way to pass the parameter via POST to the process action in the controller, so it's hidden from the user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

anyting from post or get all can be catch,there is a way to make your data more secure, example ：

1. your client and sever have a key like `$saltKey = 'only myselef know string'`
2. make encrypt string to be verify $encrypt = md5($saltkey.$questions.$clientIPOrOtheruniqueStrings)
3. change your route 
   `Route::post('process/{questions}/{encrypt}',
       'AppController@processApplication'
   );`
4. post data take $encrypt
5. on your server side verify encrypt: `if (Input::get('encrypt') ===     md5($saltkey.Input::get('question').$clientIPOrOtheruniqueStrings)) {
   }`

just an example for encrypt,hope this will give you an idea